# Differences between acpi thermal zone and lm-sensors on the cpu temperature

Tags: 20.04, cpu, acpi, temperature, lm-sensors

I'd like to monitor the CPU temperature, but I found that both paths contain cpu temp info, x86_pkg_temp under `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone2/temp` and cores' temp under `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/temp*_input`.

What is the difference between the x86_pkg_temp of ACPI thermal zone and the core temp monitored by lm-sensors? Which one is more accurate?

Comment: A typical PC has dozens of thermal sensors that measure different things.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm